# Symbolic computation under certain assumptions

Tags: matrix, symbolic, linear-algebra

Assume that I have a matrix $M$ and I'm doing some operations on it. Is there a way to specify that two variables satisfy an equation say $x=y^2$ and then let Mathematica compute under that assumption? I would like to have Mathematica recognize when it can't divide by a certain expression during row reduction and also to simplify expressions by setting things to zero that have this polynomial as a factor.

I realize that some of this requires Mathematica to factorize polynomials, so it can't be very fast.

Comment: Seems to be covered [here](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/60365/computing-kernels-of-a-matrix-in-distinct-cases), which is either you or someone else asking a more direct form of the question. If that does not seem like it handles your case then you'll need to be more specific as to what is wanted.